# Reduce If Statements For MySQL Query

Tags: php, oop, api, class-design

I know there are duplicates of this question, and the answer was to refactor the code.

However I'm not sure where to begin with this particular function.

I'm practising my OOP API skills in PHP5 and decided to write my own little Database API.

I have a function with 4 nested if statements, Im not even sure if 4 nested if's are a lot.

But this piece of code just seems messy to me and was wondering if anybody could provide any tips of how to optimise, reduce if's etc.

How would this kind of function be written in a real-world scenario?

My Code Follows:

```
public function custom_query( $sql_query_string, $single_column = false){

    $link = $this->_Link_ID;

    // IF LINK IS VALID RESOURCE
    if ( is_resource( $link ) ) {

        $query_resource = mysql_query( $sql_query_string, $link );

        // IF QUERY WAS VALID
        if ( is_resource( $query_resource ) ) {

            $this->_Query_ID = $query_resource;

            $row_count = mysql_num_rows( $query_resource );

            // IF $ROW_COUNT IS A NUMBER, VALID ROWS WERE FOUND
            if ( is_numeric( $row_count ) ) {

                if ( $single_column ){

                    $result_set = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query_resource );
                    return $result_set;
                }

                else {

                    $result_set = array();
                    for ( $row = 0; $row < $row_count; $row++ ) {
                        $result_set[$row] = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query_resource );
                    }
                    return ( object ) array ( 'row_count' => $row_count, 'result_set' => $result_set );
                }
            }

            else {
                die( "Failed To Retrieve Row Count Query: $sql_query_string MySQL Error: " . mysql_error( $link ) );
            }
        }
        else {
            die( "Invalid Query : $query_string. MySql : " . mysql_error( $link ) );
        }
    }
    else {
        die( "Query attempted without valid link resource.  Query : $query_string" );
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: In a real world scenario, you do not handle errors with die().

Comment: How would you handle them? and why NOT use die? Just asking

Comment: There are alternative answers below using either error codes or exceptions. They allow you to trap the error at an appropriate level and report something meaningful to the user. You never want to present them with a query string. It's a useful debug aid, but it has no place in a real application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to stop using `die()` in your function you can rewrite your code to form:

```php
class Yours {
  protected $errno = 0;
  protected $error = '';

  public function custom_query( $sql_query_string, $single_column = false){

    $link = $this->_Link_ID;

    // IF LINK IS VALID RESOURCE
    if ( !is_resource( $link ) ){
       $this->error = "Query attempted without valid link resource.  Query : $query_string";
       $this->errno = -1;
       return null;
    }
    ...
  }

}
```

Or you can use exceptions;

```php
  public function custom_query( $sql_query_string, $single_column = false){

    $link = $this->_Link_ID;

    // IF LINK IS VALID RESOURCE
    if ( !is_resource( $link ) ){
       throw new Exception( "Query attempted without valid link resource.  Query : $query_string", -1);
    }
    ...
  }
```

*I personally would go for exceptions... But I guess there are people that disagree with me and I'd like to read their arguments.*

**EDIT** Exception example. We'll extend php [Extension class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php):

```php
class DbException {
  protected $sql;

  public __construct( $message = "", $code = 0, $sql = '', $previous = NULL){
    parent::__construct( $message, $code, $previous);
    $this->sql = $sql;
  }

  public function getSql(){
    return $this->sql;
  }
}

// In model:
throw new DbException( "Query attempted without valid link resource.", -1, $query);

// In main application:
try {
  ob_start();
  // run whole application
} catch( DbException &e){
  ob_clean(); // Suppress all output so far

  echo "<html><body><div class="error">" . htmlspecialchars( $e->getMessage()) . "</div>";
  if( NOT_IN_PRODUCTION){
    echo "<div class='sql'>" . htmlspecialchars( $e->getSql()) . "</div>";
  }
  echo "</body></html>";
}
```

Exceptions:

- provide backtrace (for easy debugging)
- can be caught by type (and therefore you can handle them in appropriate place or let them propagate to main application)
- can contain additional info for better debugging

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have a problem with `die`-ing in the middle of the function, you can save some intendation space by simply negating the `if`s:

```
public function custom_query( $sql_query_string, $single_column = false){

    $link = $this->_Link_ID;

    // IF LINK IS VALID RESOURCE
    if ( !is_resource( $link ) ) die( "Query attempted without valid link resource.  Query : $query_string" );

    $query_resource = mysql_query( $sql_query_string, $link );

    // IF QUERY WAS VALID
    if ( !is_resource( $query_resource ) ) die( "Invalid Query : $query_string. MySql : " . mysql_error( $link ) );

    $this->_Query_ID = $query_resource;

    $row_count = mysql_num_rows( $query_resource );

    // IF $ROW_COUNT IS A NUMBER, VALID ROWS WERE FOUND
    if ( !is_numeric( $row_count ) ) die( "Failed To Retrieve Row Count Query: $sql_query_string MySQL Error: " . mysql_error( $link ) );

    if ( $single_column ) {

        $result_set = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query_resource );
        return $result_set;
    }

    else {

        $result_set = array();
        for ( $row = 0; $row < $row_count; $row++ ) {
            $result_set[$row] = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query_resource );
        }
        return ( object ) array ( 'row_count' => $row_count, 'result_set' => $result_set );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it bad practise to DIE in the middle of a function? I just saw it in other examples and thought is what the 'way to do it'

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch it's good practice (when you're developing a web) to display error in form: `<html><body>blah blah blah...<div>We apologize for error: Failed to retrieve count</body></html>` not raw text in the middle of "nowhere" (maybe in a middle of `<img here />` where user without displaying code won't see an error) + don't show your queries to user, I'll extend my answer with good example.

Comment: AFAIK there is no consensus, wether this is bad practice. I personally avoid it, instead (in your example) I'd give back an error code INT - when calling the function, `is_array()` means OK, else means error, the int tells which.